Pusher websocket URL triggering events and sending data
I am trying to trigger events and send data to websocket URL on the specific public channel, via pusher.js library. I am currently testing in postman. I am able to connect to websocket URL and subscribe to the channel but cannot trigger events and send data to the event.
Here is what I have tried. I can connect to websocket URL and subscribe to the channel as screenshot below.

Now when I try to trigger event and send data, it throw the error as marked in screenshot below. Here is the error in pusher response Unsupported event received on socket: my-event"

As per the official docs of pusher https://pusher.com/docs/channels/library_auth_reference/pusher-websockets-protocol/#channel-events-pusher-channels-greater-client,
This should be the correct way to trigger events but it is not working. Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you
